# arabic text get reversed in <pre> tag in ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, arabic

I am having real problem with Arabic text in `<pre>` tag

For example if I put this code in a page view

```
    <pre>
        &lt;html>
        &lt;head>
            &lt;title>First HTML Page&lt;/title>
        &lt;/head>
        &lt;body>
            &lt;h1><span>اول صفحة ويب</span>&lt;/h1>
            &lt;p>هذه أول فقرة ننشؤها في أول صفحة&lt;/p>
        &lt;/body>
        &lt;/html>

     </pre>
```

I get this display in browser

[image: arabic text reversed]

Here you can see that the arabic text is reversed

This happens just in ASP.NET Core MVC. In other frameworks, the text is displayed correctly.

I've tried to change the `dir` and the `lang` attributes but it does not help.

Comment: This could be related to how your editor/IDE is displaying arabic characters.

Comment: No the problem is after starting the server and opening the web page in a web browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code snippet and reproduced the issue in my side, I noticed that the content in the page is wrong but in F12 is right, so I'm afraid the browser deal with specific language content automatically for the elements in `<pre>` tag... So I tried to change the direction manually with the style. How do you think about it?

[image]

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi: bidi-override;color:red">اول صفحة ويب</div>
        <span>اول صفحة ويب</span>
        <p>هذه أول فقرة ننشؤها في أول صفحة</p>
    </div>
    <pre >
        &lt;html>
        &lt;head>
            &lt;title>First HTML Page&lt;/title>
        &lt;/head>
        &lt;body>
            &lt;h1><span style="direction:rtl;unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">اول صفحة ويب</span>&lt;/h1>
            &lt;h1><span>اول صفحة ويب</span>&lt;/h1>
            &lt;p>هذه أول فقرة ننشؤها في أول صفحة&lt;/p>
        &lt;/body>
        &lt;/html>

     </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's sufficient for me for now... Thank you